# Getting error while setting password symbols using Python

Tags: python

I could not set the value for password symbols properly using Python. I am getting the below error.

```
File "password.py", line 2
    def get_random_string(length=20, symbolgroups='"0123456789", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "!@#$%^&*():<>"'/|}{[]`\"):
                                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My code is below:

```
def get_random_string(length=20, symbolgroups='"0123456789", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "!@#$%^&*():<>"'/|}{[]`\")

    if length is None:
        length = settings.PASSWORD_LENGTH

    r = random.SystemRandom()
    password = [r.choice(s) for s in symbolgroups]
    r.shuffle(password)
    password = password[:length]
    length -= len(password)
    symbols = ''.join(symbolgroups)
    password.extend([r.choice(symbols) for _i in xrange(length)])
    r.shuffle(password)
    return ''.join(password)
```

In the first line I am trying to set all letter with special characters to symbol group to generate the password but in editor window its showing the error. Here I need to set all letter,numbers and special characters to `symbolgroups` variable.

Comment: Do you think you should tell us what the error is?

Comment: No, Actually I am using the sublime text editor so there its showing the red mark.

Comment: Well compile your program and post the error.

Comment: I added the error in my post.

Comment: You didn't think that the double quote would end the string started with a double quote?

Comment: Can you please modify this ? i had tried but it was showing the same error.

Comment: @satya: it looks like the answer below can be accepted. Would you do so, to thank this person for their work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the `"` in your string literal.

- `"foo\"bar'baz"`
- `'foo"bar\'baz'`
- `"""foo"bar'baz"""`
- `'''foo"bar'baz'''`